# How to solve VBA Excel code Run time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner to macros. When I try to execute the code I got a runt time error 91 message

```
Sub Worksheet_Functions()

    Dim HighestScore As Integer
    Dim LowestScore As Integer

    Dim TopScore As Range
    Dim BottomScore As Range

    LowestScore = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("B1", "B5"))
    HighestScore = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B1", "B5"))

    Set TopScore = Range("B1,B5").Find(What:=HighestScore)
    Set BottomScore = Range("B1,B5").Find(What:=Lowesscore)

    Range("A7").Value = "lowest score is "
    Range("A8").Value = "Highest score is"

    Range("B7").Value = BottomScore.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    Range("B8").Value = TopScore.Offset(-1, 0).Value        

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Option Explicit`, run *Debug/Compile* and fix the error you get. Do you then still get RTE 91? And check the result of `BottomScore` because `BottomScore.Offset(-1, 0)` might be out of the sheet in case it is on the top of the sheet.

Comment: Did you fix the compile errors you got? It would also behelpful if you had told at which line you get the RTE 91. I guess at `Range("B7").Value = BottomScore.Offset(-1, 0).Value`.  Please have a look at my answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code. Please have a look at the comments

```
Option Explicit

Sub Worksheet_Functions()

    Dim HighestScore As Integer
    Dim LowestScore As Integer

    Dim TopScore As Range
    Dim BottomScore As Range

    LowestScore = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("B1", "B5"))
    HighestScore = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B1", "B5"))

    Set TopScore = Range("B1,B5").Find(What:=HighestScore)
    ' In the posted code was a typo. 
    ' Use Option Explicit to avoid these kind of errors.
    Set BottomScore = Range("B1,B5").Find(What:=LowestScore)

    Range("A7").Value = "lowest score is "
    Range("A8").Value = "Highest score is"

    ' Find method returned  a result only if BottomScore is not nothing
    If Not BottomScore Is Nothing Then
        ' In case the result is in the first row you can't go one row above
        If BottomScore.Row > 1 Then
            Range("B7").Value = BottomScore.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    End If

    ' The same if conditions as with Bottomscore
    If Not TopScore Is Nothing Then
        If TopScore.Row > 1 Then
            Range("B8").Value = TopScore.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```